# Rsync Grabing Only New Files

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a set of files in storage, and I would like to get only the new files and put it in another directory. Is there a way to do this?

For example:

The "old files" are contained in:
folder/oldfiles

I would like the new files coming in from rsync to be put in folder/ [and my script would put it in oldfiles, after the file has been processed]

Is there anyway to do this with rsync?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `rsync --ignore-existing --dry-run --verbose SOURCE PROCESSED > OUTPUTFILE`
2. Process `OUTPUTFILE` to make sure it only contains file names
3. Use `rsync --files-from=OUTPUTFILE SOURCE PROCESSING`
4. Process each file in PROCESSING and move it to PROCESSED

Of course, you will want to add your usual options to the first rsync comand, e.g. `--archive` or `--recursive`.

Comment: 1. Requires the -v option.

Comment: 3. the source is required